# How to save user specific arrays in Mailchimp

Tags: arrays, mailchimp

For quite a while I am struggling with how to save custom user specific arrays of data in Mailchimp.

Simple example: I want to save the project ids for a user in Mailchimp and in best case be able to use them there properly as well. Let's say user fritz@frey.com has the 5 project ids 12345, 25345, 21342, 23424 and 48935. Why is there no array merge field that let's me save this array of project ids to a user?! (Or is there one and I am just blind...)

I know I can do drop down fields to put users in multiple groups, like types of projects for example, but the solution can hardly be a drop down with all (several thousand) project ids and I check the ones the user is a part of (and I doubt that Mailchimp would support that solution for a large number of group items anyways).

Oh and of course I could make the field myself by abusing a string field and connect the project ids with commas or a json string but that seems neither like a clean solution nor could I use the data properly in Mailchimp (as far as I know).

I googled quite a bit and couldn't find anything helpful sadly... :(

So? Can anybody enlighten me? :)
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have already arrived at the correct answer: there is no "array" type, other than the interests type, which is global and not quite the same as an array.

The best solution here sort of depends on your data. If each project ID will have many different subscribers attached to it, and there won't be too many of them active at any given time, I'd just use interests. If you think there may be dozens of project ids active simultaneously, I'd not store this data on the subscribers at all, instead I'd build static segments for each project, and add users to them.

If projects won't have a bunch of subscribers associated, I'd store the data on your end and/or continue using the comma-separated string field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very sad that Mailchimp lacks that functionality acutally. :( We will probably end up just saving the data only on our end and in the future therefore use less Mailchimp.